# How to prevent hotlinking in Android?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have an application which has a SQLite database. The SQLite database is updated via JSON once a day. I chose JSON because I won't have to update and reupload my Android application like a patch extension file. Anyways, how can I prevent someone from viewing the JSON url and using it for himself? The only way I thought of approaching the problem would be encrypting.

Comment: How would you prevent someone from running your app in an emulator, stopping it, and scraping the data out of there?